# Where is the error in creating the DailyData class?

Tags: python, class

I am just starting to learn Python, and part of one of my assignments includes creating classes needed for a later project. It is a simple project, so there are only two classes being used:

| Stock | Class (info for an individual stock) |
| --- | --- |
| symbol | Variable (stock ticker symbol) |
| name | Variable (name of company) |
| shares | Variable (number of shares owned) |
| -------- | ------------------------------------ |
| add_data(stock_data) | Method (used to add a day of price and volume history to stock) |

| DailyData | Class (info for day of stock price and volume history) |
| --- | --- |
| date | Variable (date) |
| close | Variable (stock closing price for the day) |
| volume | Variable (number of shares traded for the day) |

The assignment is to create the classes and then use a Unit Test to make sure the classes have the proper behavior. I successfully created the stock class, but I keep getting errors for DailyData. I'm pretty sure that it's something simple that I'm missing, but I need a nudge in the right direction.

Here is the code I have written:

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, symbol, name, shares):
        self.symbol=0
        self.name=0
        self.shares=0
        self.DataList=[]
    def add_data(self,stock_data):
        self.DataList.append(stock_data)

class DailyData:
    def __init__(self, date, close, volume):
        self.date=0
        self.close=(0)
        self.volume=(0)
```

Since the UnitTest was successful for the Stock part, I tried to mimic it for the DailyData, which is coming back with errors on all parts.

UnitTest Code:

```
# Unit Test - Do Not Change Code Below This Line *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
# main() is used for unit testing only. It will run when stock_class.py is run.
# Run this to test your class code. Once you have eliminated all errors, you are
# ready to continue with the next part of the project.

def main():
    error_count = 0
    error_list = []
    print("Unit Testing Starting---")
    # Test Add Stock
    print("Testing Add Stock...",end="")
    try:
        testStock = Stock("TEST","Test Company",100)
        print("Successful!")
    except:
        print("***Adding Stock Failed!")
        error_count = error_count+1
        error_list.append("Stock Constructor Error")
    # Test Change Symbol
    print("Test Change Symbol...",end="")
    try:
        testStock.symbol = "NEWTEST"
        if testStock.symbol == "NEWTEST":
            print("Successful!")
        else:
            print("***ERROR! Symbol change unsuccessful.")
            error_count = error_count+1
            error_list.append("Symbol Change Error")
    except:
        print("***ERROR! Symbol change failed.")
        error_count = error_count+1
        error_list.append("Symbol Change Failure")
    print("Test Change Name...",end="")
    try:
        testStock.name = "New Test Company"
        if testStock.name == "New Test Company":
            print("Successful!")
        else:
            print("***ERROR! Name change unsuccessful.")
            error_count = error_count+1
            error_list.append("Name Change Error")
    except:
        print("***ERROR! Name change failed.")
        error_count = error_count+1
        error_list.append("Name Change Failure")
        print("Test Change Name...",end="")
    try:
        testStock.shares = 2000
        if testStock.shares == 2000:
            print("Successful!")
        else:
            print("***ERROR! Shares change unsuccessful.")
            error_count = error_count+1
            error_list.append("Shares Change Error")
    except:
        print("***ERROR! Shares change failed.")
        error_count = error_count+1
        error_list.append("Shares Change Failure")
        

    # Test add daily data
    print("Creating daily stock data...",end="")
    daily_data_error = False
    try:
        dayData = DailyData("1/1/20",float(14.50),float(100000))
        testStock.add_data(dayData)
        if testStock.DataList[0].date != "1/1/20":
            error_count = error_count + 1
            daily_data_error = True
            error_list.append("Add Daily Data - Problem with Date")
        if testStock.DataList[0].close != 14.50:
            error_count = error_count + 1
            daily_data_error = True
            error_list.append("Add Daily Data - Problem with Closing Price")
        if testStock.DataList[0].volume != 100000:
            error_count = error_count + 1
            daily_data_error = True
            error_list.append("Add Daily Data - Problem with Volume")  
    except:
        print("***ERROR! Add daily data failed.")
        error_count = error_count + 1
        error_list.append("Add daily data Failure!")
        daily_data_error = True
    if daily_data_error == True:
        print("***ERROR! Creating daily data failed.")
    else:
        print("Successful!")
    
    if (error_count) == 0:
        print("Congratulations - All Tests Passed")
    else:
        print("-=== Problem List - Please Fix ===-")
        for em in error_list:
            print(em)
    print("Goodbye")

# Program Starts Here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run unit testing only if run as a stand-alone script
    main()
```

Any insight you can give would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__` of `DailyData` you set all your variables to 0 regardless off what is being passed in.

So when the test does `dayData = DailyData("1/1/20",float(14.50),float(100000))` those arguments are completely ignored and the variables are all set to 0. The test fails because it takes that implementation, adds it into `testStock` with `testStock.add_data(dayData)` and immediately checks to see if the date supplied makes it through with `if testStock.DataList[0].date != "1/1/20":`, and all it finds is a `0`.

I think you may have been meaning to supply default values for the arguments, which should be done in the function definition. Consider instead:

```
class DailyData:
    def __init__(self, date=0, close=0, volume=0):
        self.date=date
        self.close=close
        self.volume=volume
```